# preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'am trying to get all {{product.smth}} with preg_match_all, but if i have few of this in one line i get wrong result.

Example:

```
$smth = '<name>{{product.name}}</name><getname>{{product.getName()}}</getname>';

$pattern = '/\{\{product\.(.*)\}\}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $smth, $matches);

//returns '{{product.name}}</name><getname>{{product.getName()}}'
//instad of '{{product.name}}' and '{{product.getName()}}'
```

What iam doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: @Ωmega I prefer the modifier though :) Note that ungreedy is just toggled with it, so `/.*?/U` is greedy for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [repetition is greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Either make it ungreedy by using `.*?` or better yet: disallow the `}` character for the repetition:

```
$pattern = '/\{\{product\.([^}]*)\}\}/';
```

If you do want to allow single `}` in that value (like `{{product.some{thing}here}}`), the equivalent solution uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$pattern = '/\{\{product\.((?:(?!\}\}).)*)\}\}/';
```

For every single character included in `.*` it checks that that character doesn't mark the start of a `}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll work if you change `.*` to `.*?` this will make it *lazy* instead of *greedy* and it will try to match as little as possible - so, till the first occurance of `}}` rather than the last.

Comment: Isn't it just called ungreedy? Otherwise you'll be going from one sin to the other :)

Comment: _Lazy quantifiers are sometimes also called "ungreedy" or "reluctant"_ source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html